# Beautifulsoup Href extraction is either Hidden or not working

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am trying to extract the text marked in yellow from this image -

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StU48.png)

I tried all the codes available to extract the link, for e.g. I used codes like -

```
links = [a.get('href') for a in soup.find_all('a', { "id" : "price-and-shop-body" }, href=True)]
links
```

Nothing works.

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Does `print(soup)` have the anchor tag at all? Also, please include your full code/link

Comment: may be you doesn't print it. you can put your code in it.

Comment: the image is the screenshot of the html. When I look into the page source of the page, I am unable to see the href link. The link shows up only on Inspect element in google chrome. I am assuming its because its coming from some js. I tried print and it comes up empty.

Comment: [Link](https://www.consumerreports.org/products/drip-coffee-maker/behmor-connected-alexa-enabled-temperature-control-396982/overview/)

Comment: did you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse text from an image which is not at all possible using BeautifulSoup. You can use BeautifulSoup to parse Web Pages, and definitely not images.

However, you can use [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) which is a python library for Optical Character Recognition (OCR). This [Blogpost](https://www.simplifiedpython.net/how-to-extract-text-from-image-in-python/) might help you.

Comment: Its not an image, its a screenshot of the html.

Comment: Can you please share the URL you are trying to parse?

Comment: [Link](https://www.consumerreports.org/products/drip-coffee-maker/behmor-connected-alexa-enabled-temperature-control-396982/overview/)

Comment: hi shiv, did u take a look?